# Problem with module mailalerts Prestashop

Tags: module, prestashop

I used the prestashop debug and this is the error it gives me and I don't know how to fix it.

> ContextErrorException Notice: Undefined index: navigationPipe
>
> in
>   2be2345a97d28ff58ebcd22196932ea8bbcedf26_2.file.mailalerts-account.tpl.php
>   line 63

Comment: what is your prestashop version ? The module seems quite old, so that smarty variable can have been renamed or deleted ...

Comment: whats ur prestashop version ?

Comment: 1.7.6.1 prestashop

Comment: v3.7.0 mail alerts

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the line of this file:

```
WEBSITE/var/cache/dev/smarty/compile/2b/e2/34/2be2345a97d28ff58ebcd22196932ea8bbcedf26_2.file.mailalerts-account.tpl.php
```

Regards

Comment: You can also view the original template [here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/mailalerts/blob/6c43f7f665979a40bb294d1a796127108f7b7061/views/templates/front/mailalerts-account.tpl#L59) and [in the corresponding controller](https://github.com/PrestaShop/mailalerts/blob/master/controllers/front/account.php) there is not assigment of a ``navigationPipe`` variable, so it should come of the parent Controller

Comment: liine 63 </a><span class="navigation-pipe"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['navigationPipe']->value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>

Comment: @daniellandete whats ur prestashop version ?